# break line within mathescape in listing

Tags: listings, line-breaking

How do I solve the evergreen problem of breaking a long equation into multiple lines but this time within the `lstlisting[mathescape]` environment. Attached is the minimum working example.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape]
$\displaystyle
a = b =c =  d =e \\ =f =g =e =h = \alpha
$
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want that you need some kind of multi-line math environment, eg `aligned`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{listings,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape]
$\begin{aligned}
a = b =c =  d =e \\ =f =g =e =h = \alpha
\end{aligned}$
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Obviously :). Thank you. Aligned make it right aligned. How do we do left aligned? fligned doesn't work in this environment. Should this be another question?

Comment: @Sandeep you could just put a `&` at the start of each line